# Unable to link git2-rs because of many undefined references to gcry-* symbols

Tags: linux, rust, linker, dependencies

#### Environment

- Linux (Pop!_OS if that matters, which means it's almost Ubuntu).

```
 $ cargo --version
cargo 1.41.0 (626f0f40e 2019-12-03)

 $ rustc --version
rustc 1.41.0 (5e1a79984 2020-01-27)
```

#### What I did

```
$ cargo new xxx
     Created binary (application) `xxx` package
```

I edited `Cargo.toml` to look like this:

```
[package]
  name = "xxx"
  version = "0.1.0"
  authors = ["Martin Marconcini <xxx@xxx.com>"]
  edition = "2018"

 [dependencies]
 git2 = "0.12.0"
```

And `main.rs`:

```
use git2::Repository;

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");

    let repo = match Repository::open("fake/path") {
        Ok(repo) => repo,
        Err(e) => panic!("Failed to init {}", e),
    };
}
```

#### Issue

I know `fake/path` won't work but I expect the program to build, link, and panic when run. Instead, when I do cargo run, here is what I get:

```
 $ cargo run
    Updating crates.io index
   Compiling libc v0.2.67
   Compiling pkg-config v0.3.17
   Compiling autocfg v1.0.0
   Compiling smallvec v1.2.0
   Compiling matches v0.1.8
   Compiling bitflags v1.2.1
   Compiling log v0.4.8
   Compiling cfg-if v0.1.10
   Compiling percent-encoding v2.1.0
   Compiling openssl-probe v0.1.2
   Compiling unicode-bidi v0.3.4
   Compiling unicode-normalization v0.1.12
   Compiling jobserver v0.1.21
   Compiling idna v0.2.0
   Compiling cc v1.0.50
   Compiling url v2.1.1
   Compiling libz-sys v1.0.25
   Compiling openssl-sys v0.9.54
   Compiling libssh2-sys v0.2.16
   Compiling libgit2-sys v0.11.0+0.99.0
   Compiling git2 v0.12.0
   Compiling xxx v0.1.0 (/home/martin/dev/rust/xxx)
warning: unused variable: `repo`
 --> src/main.rs:6:9
  |
6 |     let repo = match Repository::open("/fake/path") {
  |         ^^^^ help: consider prefixing with an underscore: `_repo`
  |
  = note: `#[warn(unused_variables)]` on by default

error: linking with `cc` failed: exit code: 1
  |
  = note: "cc" "-Wl,--as-needed" "-Wl,-z,noexecstack" "-m64" "-L" "/home/martin/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib" "/home/martin/dev/rust/xxx/target/debug/deps/xxx-fe6ac189d82a9620.1g3apxivazecmby1.rcgu.o" "/home/martin/dev/rust/xxx/target/debug/deps/xxx-fe6ac189d82a9620.1ktaa7mhzl12qb8s.rcgu.o" "/home/martin/dev/rust/xxx/target/debug/deps/xxx-fe6ac189d82a9620.1of15nz9rghhwcp.rcgu.o" "/home/martin/dev/rust/xxx/target/debug/deps/xxx-fe6ac189d82a9620.1pzhxyvu6x3rpyd4.rcgu.o" "/home/martin/dev/rust/xxx/target/debug/deps/xxx-fe6ac189d82a9620.1xjrgwir8ul0gxyn.rcgu.o" "/home/martin/dev/rust/xxx/target/debug/deps/xxx-fe6ac189d82a9620.236nnnkop2p1q7o.rcgu.o" "/home/martin/dev/rust/xxx/target/debug/deps/xxx-fe6ac189d82a9620.346upd227a1u5o1x.rcgu.o" "/home/martin/dev/rust/xxx/target/debug/deps/xxx-fe6ac189d82a9620.4vpli3o8gp9bo7bb.rcgu.o" "/home/martin/dev/rust/xxx/target/debug/deps/xxx-fe6ac189d82a9620.fjvxd6ccfznqzmo.rcgu.o" "-o" "/home/martin/dev/rust/xxx/target/debug/deps/xxx-fe6ac189d82a9620" "/home/martin/dev/rust/xxx/target/debug/deps/xxx-fe6ac189d82a9620.2bpv5j881nolkdhg.rcgu.o" "-Wl,--gc-sections" "-pie" "-Wl,-zrelro" "-Wl,-znow" "-nodefaultlibs" "-L" "/home/martin/dev/rust/xxx/target/debug/deps" "-L" "/home/martin/dev/rust/xxx/target/debug/build/libgit2-sys-9a380c1f1af1ff52/out/build" "-L" "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu" "-L" "/home/martin/dev/rust/xxx/target/debug/build/libssh2-sys-76c9f6db4b487643/out/build" "-L" "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu" "-L" "/home/martin/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib" "-Wl,-Bstatic" "/home/martin/dev/rust/xxx/target/debug/deps/libgit2-e4070b896a12b23e.rlib" "/home/martin/dev/rust/xxx/target/debug/deps/libopenssl_probe-02ad0051245c142f.rlib" "/home/martin/dev/rust/xxx/target/debug/deps/liburl-752d8a16592303c8.rlib" "/home/martin/dev/rust/xxx/target/debug/deps/libpercent_encoding-3f375297ed36a953.rlib" "/home/martin/dev/rust/xxx/target/debug/deps/libidna-a849b89d54cc2589.rlib" "/home/martin/dev/rust/xxx/target/debug/deps/libunicode_normalization-81788f9135a21d94.rlib" "/home/martin/dev/rust/xxx/target/debug/deps/libsmallvec-e36b82e338fe18d3.rlib" "/home/martin/dev/rust/xxx/target/debug/deps/libunicode_bidi-901a064d2af6777d.rlib" "/home/martin/dev/rust/xxx/target/debug/deps/libmatches-ccee7833d11c4363.rlib" "/home/martin/dev/rust/xxx/target/debug/deps/liblog-aba47d2dbe489265.rlib" "/home/martin/dev/rust/xxx/target/debug/deps/libcfg_if-fd0f59c38961bb3a.rlib" "/home/martin/dev/rust/xxx/target/debug/deps/liblibgit2_sys-b077f325e2a7224c.rlib" "/home/martin/dev/rust/xxx/target/debug/deps/liblibssh2_sys-187467b0efb35c13.rlib" "/home/martin/dev/rust/xxx/target/debug/deps/libopenssl_sys-b21cd1cefc781387.rlib" "/home/martin/dev/rust/xxx/target/debug/deps/liblibz_sys-c72b1cae7b178c73.rlib" "/home/martin/dev/rust/xxx/target/debug/deps/liblibc-a68ece9bb60c0ea2.rlib" "/home/martin/dev/rust/xxx/target/debug/deps/libbitflags-468acf5fe2f3e68a.rlib" "-Wl,--start-group" "/home/martin/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libstd-9d59e25e2eb2384d.rlib" "/home/martin/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libpanic_unwind-4affccee0db9d60e.rlib" "/home/martin/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libhashbrown-cd6b495608e342d1.rlib" "/home/martin/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/librustc_std_workspace_alloc-347d88a586b28b4c.rlib" "/home/martin/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libbacktrace-46f3dc0b263b900a.rlib" "/home/martin/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libbacktrace_sys-6789aa6fbcfdf14c.rlib" "/home/martin/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/librustc_demangle-9f9436f1ab051941.rlib" "/home/martin/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libunwind-ad8ec269e6d86d01.rlib" "/home/martin/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcfg_if-3699f95d33475c27.rlib" "/home/martin/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/liblibc-fe798441633702e1.rlib" "/home/martin/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/liballoc-979288990efe6065.rlib" "/home/martin/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/librustc_std_workspace_core-2181f1e1dd7399d7.rlib" "/home/martin/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcore-b8952fd765001238.rlib" "-Wl,--end-group" "/home/martin/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcompiler_builtins-e99fedbd2b621435.rlib" "-Wl,-Bdynamic" "-lz" "-lssl" "-lcrypto" "-lz" "-lutil" "-ldl" "-lutil" "-ldl" "-lrt" "-lpthread" "-lgcc_s" "-lc" "-lm" "-lrt" "-lpthread" "-lutil" "-lutil"
  = note: /usr/bin/ld: /home/martin/dev/rust/xxx/target/debug/deps/liblibssh2_sys-187467b0efb35c13.rlib(libgcrypt.o): in function `_libssh2_rsa_new':
          (.text+0x48): undefined reference to `gcry_sexp_build'
          /usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x77): undefined reference to `gcry_sexp_build'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/martin/dev/rust/xxx/target/debug/deps/liblibssh2_sys-187467b0efb35c13.rlib(libgcrypt.o): in function `_libssh2_rsa_sha1_verify':
          (.text+0xcb): undefined reference to `gcry_md_hash_buffer'
          /usr/bin/ld: (.text+0xe8): undefined reference to `gcry_sexp_build'
          /usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x103): undefined reference to `gcry_sexp_build'
          /usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x118): undefined reference to `gcry_pk_verify'
          /usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x123): undefined reference to `gcry_sexp_release'
          /usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x12d): undefined reference to `gcry_sexp_release'
          /usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x166): undefined reference to `gcry_sexp_release'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/martin/dev/rust/xxx/target/debug/deps/liblibssh2_sys-187467b0efb35c13.rlib(libgcrypt.o): in function `_libssh2_dsa_new':
          (.text+0x1cc): undefined reference to `gcry_sexp_build'
          /usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x203): undefined reference to `gcry_sexp_build'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/martin/dev/rust/xxx/target/debug/deps/liblibssh2_sys-187467b0efb35c13.rlib(libgcrypt.o): in function `_libssh2_rsa_sha1_sign':
          (.text+0x73f): undefined reference to `gcry_sexp_build'
          /usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x757): undefined reference to `gcry_pk_sign'
          /usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x763): undefined reference to `gcry_sexp_release'
          /usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x77d): undefined reference to `gcry_sexp_find_token'
          /usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x79d): undefined reference to `gcry_sexp_nth_data'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/martin/dev/rust/xxx/target/debug/deps/liblibssh2_sys-187467b0efb35c13.rlib(libgcrypt.o): in function `_libssh2_dsa_sha1_sign':
          (.text+0x87c): undefined reference to `gcry_sexp_build'
          /usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x896): undefined reference to `gcry_pk_sign'
          /usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x8a2): undefined reference to `gcry_sexp_release'
          /usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x8d0): undefined reference to `gcry_sexp_find_token'
          /usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x8f3): undefined reference to `gcry_sexp_nth_data'
          /usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x937): undefined reference to `gcry_sexp_release'
          /usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x946): undefined reference to `gcry_sexp_release'
          /usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x985): undefined reference to `gcry_sexp_release'
          /usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x998): undefined reference to `gcry_sexp_find_token'
          /usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x9b2): undefined reference to `gcry_sexp_nth_data'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/martin/dev/rust/xxx/target/debug/deps/liblibssh2_sys-187467b0efb35c13.rlib(libgcrypt.o): in function `_libssh2_dsa_sha1_verify':
          (.text+0xa62): undefined reference to `gcry_md_hash_buffer'
          /usr/bin/ld: (.text+0xa84): undefined reference to `gcry_sexp_build'
          /usr/bin/ld: (.text+0xab2): undefined reference to `gcry_sexp_build'
          /usr/bin/ld: (.text+0xac9): undefined reference to `gcry_pk_verify'
          /usr/bin/ld: (.text+0xad4): undefined reference to `gcry_sexp_release'
          /usr/bin/ld: (.text+0xade): undefined reference to `gcry_sexp_release'
          /usr/bin/ld: (.text+0xb16): undefined reference to `gcry_sexp_release'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/martin/dev/rust/xxx/target/debug/deps/liblibssh2_sys-187467b0efb35c13.rlib(libgcrypt.o): in function `_libssh2_cipher_init':
          (.text+0xb5a): undefined reference to `gcry_cipher_get_algo_keylen'
          /usr/bin/ld: (.text+0xb6c): undefined reference to `gcry_cipher_open'
          /usr/bin/ld: (.text+0xb7f): undefined reference to `gcry_cipher_setkey'
          /usr/bin/ld: (.text+0xba4): undefined reference to `gcry_cipher_get_algo_blklen'
          /usr/bin/ld: (.text+0xbb8): undefined reference to `gcry_cipher_setiv'
          /usr/bin/ld: (.text+0xbc5): undefined reference to `gcry_cipher_close'
          /usr/bin/ld: (.text+0xbd1): undefined reference to `gcry_cipher_setctr'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/martin/dev/rust/xxx/target/debug/deps/liblibssh2_sys-187467b0efb35c13.rlib(libgcrypt.o): in function `_libssh2_cipher_crypt':
          (.text+0xc02): undefined reference to `gcry_cipher_encrypt'
          /usr/bin/ld: (.text+0xc11): undefined reference to `gcry_cipher_decrypt'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/martin/dev/rust/xxx/target/debug/deps/liblibssh2_sys-187467b0efb35c13.rlib(global.o): in function `libssh2_init':
          (.text+0x38): undefined reference to `gcry_control'
          collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

- I have searched online for answers, but seems like most git2-rs results don't even talk about this, which maybe means I'm missing a `-dev` dependency or something.
- I have seen [this](https://github.com/alexcrichton/git2-rs/tree/master/examples) and [this](https://siciarz.net/24-days-rust-git2/), but in both cases, there's no setup or any Cargo.toml to peek at.
- I have seen the [official GitHub repo for git2-rs](https://github.com/rust-lang/git2-rs), and compiled that with a `cargo build` and it worked.
- Have ran these two commands:

  ```
  $ pkg-config --libs openssl
  -lssl -lcrypto
  ```

  and

  ```
  $ pkg-config --cflags openssl
  ```

  ^ This one produces no output which I believe is expected.

  [image: building git2-rs]

Where do I look next? My guess is that I am missing a library, or that the version I have is not the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out (after a little bit of experimentation and luck).

The whole issue smelled like a problem with `ld` and the linking process of the C libssl library needed by git to use SSH connections.

Pop!_OS is known for including a lot of "development needed" things, so I was positive I had all that (I did).

#### How did I fix it?

I looked at the `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` directory. There are a few ".conf" files there. `x86_64-linux-gnu.conf` pointed at `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`, so I went there to see which libraries matched `libssh*`.

I found this:

```
$ ls -ls /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssh*
 312 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  316732 Sep  5  2019 libssh2.a
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 Sep  5  2019 libssh2.so -> libssh2.so.1.0.1
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 Sep  5  2019 libssh2.so.1 -> libssh2.so.1.0.1
 184 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  186856 Sep  5  2019 libssh2.so.1.0.1
1040 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1061468 Dec 10 16:24 libssh.a
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      22 Dec 10 16:24 libssh-gcrypt.so.4 -> libssh-gcrypt.so.4.8.1
 552 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  564760 Dec 10 16:24 libssh-gcrypt.so.4.8.1
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      11 Dec 10 16:24 libssh.so -> libssh.so.4
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      15 Dec 10 16:24 libssh.so.4 -> libssh.so.4.8.1
 552 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  564856 Dec 10 16:24 libssh.so.4.8.1
```

When comparing this output with a freshly installed VM that does **not** exhibit this issue, I noticed that all the `libssh2*` files did not exist in the VM.

Since the linker errors are all in gcry (which I think stands for `cryPT`), I decided to try removing the two versions and leaving only the one that works:

```
$ sudo apt remove libssh2-1-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libhttp-parser-dev libmbedtls-dev
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libgit2-dev libssh2-1-dev
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 3,700 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 412520 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing libgit2-dev:amd64 (0.27.7+dfsg.1-0.2build1) ...
Removing libssh2-1-dev:amd64 (1.8.0-2.1build1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.7-3) ...
```

After doing this, I got the expected output:

```
 $ cargo run
warning: unused variable: `repo`
 --> src/main.rs:6:9
  |
6 |     let repo = match Repository::open("fakerepo") {
  |         ^^^^ help: consider prefixing with an underscore: `_repo`
  |
  = note: `#[warn(unused_variables)]` on by default

    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.01s
     Running `target/debug/xxx`
Hello, world!
thread 'main' panicked at 'Failed to init failed to resolve path 'fakerepo': No such file or directory; class=Os (2); code=NotFound (-3)', src/main.rs:8:19
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace.
```

If I initialize a git repo and run it again, there's no error, as expected:

```
$ mkdir fakerepo; cd fakerepo ; git init ; cd ..
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/martin/dev/rust/xxx/fakerepo/.git/

$ cargo run
warning: unused variable: `repo`
 --> src/main.rs:6:9
  |
6 |     let repo = match Repository::open("fakerepo") {
  |         ^^^^ help: consider prefixing with an underscore: `_repo`
  |
  = note: `#[warn(unused_variables)]` on by default

    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.03s
     Running `target/debug/xxx`
Hello, world!
```

It appears the issue was that library. I'll investigate further to know where it came from (who installed it) and more importantly, how to make this a non-issue (there's gotta be a way to tell this whole build process which lib to pick), but that's another issue for another day.

#### What did I do to find this out?

The VM trick, was something that I've done before to solve other issues. Linux is very easy/fast to install on VMs and Gnome Boxes is already installed and configured on my Pop!_OS, so it took me 1 minute to launch it and have a freshly installed OS in front of me (ok, it was not fresh, I had to download like 150 updates in the VM) :)

Anyway, I had a [Peppermint OS](https://peppermintos.com/) install; a super light Ubuntu-based distro that doesn't have much in the way, so it was perfect for my needs. All I needed to do on Peppermint OS to get started was:

- `sudo apt install pkg-config`
- `sudo apt install libssl-dev`
- `sudo apt install curl` (yes, it doesn't come with curl)
- [Install Rust](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch01-01-installation.html) (tl;dr: `curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh`)

After doing this, I was able to run the same hello world project. When I realized it was working on this VM, I did it again on a Pop!_OS 19.10 freshly installed VM too. And again, it worked. (this surprised me, as I was incorrectly blaming "Pop_OS").

The fact that this worked on both VMs with little input from me, prompted me to keep trying on my main machine; I'm glad I did.